# Email Notification to users on Loggin in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to code program which will notify users when they are logged in through PHP & MySQL.

I tried but it did not email login when the user logged in!

Email Notification is selected by Users. If users select yes, then only it should notify them.

And the user from which it is being tested is set to `yes`

I tried:

**signin.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect($web.$_SESSION['user_name']);
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($uname,$upass))
    {

            $message = "        
Hello $uname,<br />
                        <p>You are Logged in!

                        <br /><br />
                        Thanks:)";

            $subject = "Notifier";

            $user_login->send_mail($email,$message,$subject);

        $user_login->redirect($uname);
    }
}
?>
```

**class.user.php**

```
        public function login($uname,$upass)
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
                $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
                $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                    {
                        if($userRow['userAccess']=="Y")
                    {
                        if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                        {
                         if($userRow['userNotify']=="Y")
                    {       
    return true;            
                }
                            $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                            $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();
                            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $userRow['userName'];
                            return true;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            header("Location: signin.php?error");
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: default.php");
                        exit;
                    }   
                }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: inactive.php");
                        exit;
                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: signin.php?error");
                    exit;
                }       
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }   

function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {                       
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Username="mail@gmail.com";  
        $mail->Password="password";            
        $mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com','Name');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("mail@gmail.com","Name");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
    }
```

Email Notification is selected by Users. If users select yes, then only it should notify them.

This is checked by

```
if($userRow['userNotify']=="Y")
{       
return true;            
}
```

Comment: I guess username is an unique value, so the future error you will got is if 2 same username are stored in the database you will no active the good guy, so i general email are unique or id is the unique one you have to check. or a couple in the clause where email and username can be more relevant than using the username. Regards.

Comment: @headmax `userName` and `userEmail` bot are unique... There cannot be duplicate values

Comment: Can't see where `$email` is set.

Comment: Can I get your `email function`?

Comment: @Chiru I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I got this correctly, your login action will always return `true` (of course, assuming the credentials match and everything else is correct) regardless of the user selecting or not the "Email Notification" option. It would cause the method `$user_login->send_mail($email,$message,$subject);` to be executed upon every successful login.

But your problem seem to be related to the fact that the e-mails are not hitting the inboxes of the recipients, right? Can you paste your `send_mail()` method? You can add debugs and breakpoints to make sure the flow is entering this desired method, and what data are being input.

I would also take a look at the configuration of your mail transfer agent on the server (postfix, sendmail etc.), assuming that the e-mails are not using any external SMTP service or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have nowhere declared/initialized `$email` before calling below

```
$user_login->send_mail($email,$message,$subject);
```

Comment: How and where should I declare `$email`? Email address is stored in `userEmail`

Comment: @ChiragJainBetala Then where have you declared `$userEmail` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing the question!

I went through your code and as others said, you have not defined `$email` and also if you define, your code then also will not work as

```
if($userRow['userNotify']=="Y")
                    {       
    return true;            
                }
```

will only check it will not do anything.

So as per your codes, I hope my codes will help you to sort out from all problems.

**Keeping `email function` unchangeable in `class.user.php` my edit codes goes:**

**class.user.php**

```
public function login($uname,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userAccess']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {
                     if($userRow['userNotify']=="Y")
                {
$email = $userRow['userEmail'];
$message = "Hello $uname,<br />
                        <p>You are Logged in!

                        <br /><br />
                        Thanks:)";

            $subject = "Notifier";

            require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Username="mail@gmail.com";  
        $mail->Password="password";            
        $mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com','Name');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("mail@gmail.com","Name");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
            return true;            
            }
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();
                        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $userRow['userName'];
                        return true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: signin.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: default.php");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: inactive.php");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: signin.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**signin.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect($web.$_SESSION['user_name']);
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($uname,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect($uname);
    }
}
?>
```